# Query with multiple if statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'd like to use following if statement to have the modified serial numbers on sn1 column.
How do I put the below if statements to query?

```
If Len([sn]) <= 12 Then Me.sn1 = Me.sn 
Else
     If Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And Not IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)) Then Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10)

    Else
     If Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)) Then Me.sn1 = Me.sn

    Else
     If Len([sn]) >= 14 And Not IsNumeric(Right([sn], 1)) Then Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 11)

    Else
      Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10)
```

Comment: You can just set a variable or integer and concatenate that in a query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to add a function to your database.  Create a new module and paste this in:

```
Public Function sn1(sn As String) As String
Dim StringIfs as String

StringIfs = Right(sn, 10)
If Len(sn) <= 12 Then 
   StringIfs = sn 
Else If Len(sn) = 13 And Left(sn, 1) = "S" And Not IsNumeric(Mid(sn, 2, 3)) Then 
   StringIfs = Right(sn, 10)
Else If Len(sn) = 13 And Left(sn, 1) = "S" And IsNumeric(Mid(sn, 2, 3)) Then 
   StringIfs = sn
Else If Len(sn) >= 14 And Not IsNumeric(Right(sn, 1)) Then 
   StringIfs = Right(sn, 11)
End If


  sn1 = StringIfs
End Function
```

Then, in your query, you would put something like this:

```
MyNewField: sn1(sn)
```

That is, assuming your original field in your table is called "sn".  If the field is called Boo, change the query field to MyNewField: sn1(Boo).  Get it?  You can change MyNewField to anything you want, but if the field is supposed to be called sn1 then I would suggest changing the function name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ahhh.  See my edited post above.  You MIGHT need to remove the spaces between Else and If, I can't remember if that calls for "ElseIf" or "Else If"

Comment: nowm i'm getting compile error and "Else If Len(sn) = 13 And Left(sn, 1) = "S" And Not IsNumeric(Mid(sn, 2, 3)) Then" is in Red

Answer (score 0):

If statements, written in access's flavor of SQL are formatted as:

```
IIF([condition], [true result], [false result])
```

Following this syntax, you'd write your statement as follows:

```
IIf(Len([sn]) <= 12, Me.sn1 = Me.sn, 
IIf(Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And Not IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)), Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10),
IIf(Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)), Me.sn1 = Me.sn,
IIf(Len([sn]) >= 14 And Not IsNumeric(Right([sn], 1)), Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 11),Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10)))))
```

In the query,this would look like this:

```
SELECT IIf(Len([sn]) <= 12, Me.sn1 = Me.sn, 
IIf(Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And Not IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)), Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10),
IIf(Len([sn]) = 13 And Left([sn], 1) = "S" And IsNumeric(Mid([sn], 2, 3)), Me.sn1 = Me.sn,
IIf(Len([sn]) >= 14 And Not IsNumeric(Right([sn], 1)), Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 11),Me.sn1 = Right([sn], 10))))) AS [SN1]
FROM [SN]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in access. how do I enter that statement into the query? I want the result in sn1 column when I run the query. thanks